# Nested resource under users, I want only the current_user to be able to access

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following under my `routes.rb`:

```
  resources :users do 
  resources :submitted_terms, only: [:index, :create, :show] 
  end
```

I only want the `current_user` (the logged in user) to be able to see their own `submitted_terms` in terms of the `index` and `show` views. They shouldn't be able to see anybody else's `index` and `show` views and other people shouldn't be able to see theirs.

I think I know how to implement this but it feels sort of messy to me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can before_action filter.

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [#action for which you need this filer]

  def correct_user
    @submitted_term = SubmittedTerm.find(params[:id])
    unless @submitted_term.user == current_user
      flash[:notice] = "Insuffient privlage"
      redirect_to #some path or render
    end
  end
```

you may need to change code or create new action(filter) for checking if user is logged in or not

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, but if it's in a nested route I think you need to do something like `@user = SubmittedTerm.find(params[:user_id]).user`.

Comment: you should use SubmittedTerm.find(params[:id]).user bcoz you are calling find method on SubmittedTerm .